# Illustrator scripting > select all paths using JS

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator

i need to do some tasks using illustrator js scripting and I am a bit confusing on how to select the paths that are previously draw using the software itself, so basically when I run my script with a open document with some paths, the script will select all and make something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example, to set all paths width to 10:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < documents[0].pathItems.length; i++){
    documents[0].pathItems[i].width = 10; 
  }
```

Also, you should read the official scripting guide, it helps a lot:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html